# Selenium not closing browser, launches twice

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using this hook class with selenium and cucumber. When I run a feature 2 instances start, which is a problem, also the instance doesn't close. they are running from this hook..what am I doing wrong?

```
public class WebDriverHooks {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    /**
     * Delete all cookies at the start of each scenario to avoid
     * shared state between tests
     */
    public void openBrowser() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("Called openBrowser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "//Applications//chrome//chromedriver");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @After
    /**
     * Embed a screenshot in test report if test is marked as failed
     */
    public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            try {
                scenario.write("Current Page URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
                byte[] screenshot = getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
                System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
            }
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're not taking enough care to manage your `WebDriver` instances.

Your `@After` handler only calls `.quit()` in the event of a failure, whereas your `@Before` creates a new `ChromeDriver` every time. And because your hook (and both handler methods) may potentially get called more than once (the nature of Cucumber), you may get an increasing number of Driver instances.

What you should do is:

1. Either ensure your `@After` calls `.quit()` every time, to match your `@Before`.
2. Or, more efficiently, change your `@Before` to only create a Driver if one is needed:

   ```
   if (driver == null) {
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
   ```

... and remove the `.quit()` altogether from `@After`. Shift responsibility for quitting the shared `ChromeDriver` instance up a level, either to your test runner (which we can't see) or perhaps create a shutdown hook to do it. It will need to be done at some point otherwise the browser process won't quit.

Comment: Create a shutdown hook.

    at_exit do  
      driver.quit()
   end